# Dynamic menu URL for each user role

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have the usual "my account" with redirect to "/my-account", but if I am logged as an administrator I want to redirect me  to "/other-page". I did a part of the code but I am not sure how to change that href.

```
// Replace my_account url for administrator
function nrc_replace_my_account_url(){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var my_account = document.getElementsByClassName("my_account_icon");
            my_account.a.href ="newURL"  // here I am stuck 
        </script>
    <?php }
}

add_action('init', 'nrc_replace_my_account_url');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Replace my_account url for administrator
function nrc_replace_my_account_url(){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var my_accountLink = document.querySelector(".my_account_icon a");
            my_accountLink.href ="newURL"  // here I am stuck 
        </script>
    <?php }
}

add_action('init', 'nrc_replace_my_account_url');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution for changing `a href`, using jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(".my-account-icon a").attr("href", "<?php get_site_url(); ?> /new-url")
</script>
```